# JavaScript regex - get string from within infinite number of curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract all text between curly brackets. There can be any number of curly brackets surrounding the string. However, there will be an equal number of curly braces that wrap each side of the string.

```
var string = "<div>{{foo}}} and {{{bar}}} and {{{{hahahahahahahahaha}}}}</div>"
```

needs to return

```
var array = ['foo','bar','hahahahahahahahaha']
```

I cant quite get grok it...

**Edit**

A friend has provided an answer which works:

https://regex101.com/r/zI3qL1/1

```
/\{+(.*?)\}+/g
```

As pointed out in the comments by Christian Rondeau, this answer will include the brackets in the array, AND that it will not verify if the brackets count matches. So if anyone has a valid answer for that bit of the puzzle I'll mark that as accepted. Seems a bit of a cheat to post my own answer (that a friend gave me) and claim it as accepted.

Comment: So you want to match `{text}` basically, just make sure there is at least one on each side, that should be enough, right?

Comment: You were faster than me :) Please answer your own question and mark it as accepted!

Comment: Note however that your answer will include the brackets in your array, AND that it will not verify if the brackets count matches.

Comment: Hehe - then I wont mark mine as accepted :) In any case - it wasn't me who came up with the answer. I solved the bracket inclusion by doing a further regex on each item in the array (but thats not very efficient). I'm open to better solutions :)

Comment: It's still a valid answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: "however that your answer will include the brackets in your array, AND that it will not verify if the brackets count matches." - then I'll revise the question to include that :)

Comment: why is `foo` matched when it's not surrounded by equal number of brackets?

Comment: Hi Fabricator - you're right. Its an issue Christian also raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `String.replace`. It'll only match when the number of braces match on both sides.

```js
function getParams(input){
  var matches = [];
  input.replace(/(\{+)([^}]+)(}+)/g,function(orig,lb,txt,rb){
      if (lb.length === rb.length)
        matches.push(txt);
  });
  return matches;
}
var string = "<div>{{foo}} and {{{bar}}} and {{{{hahahahahahahahaha}}}}</div>";
document.write(getParams(string));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var string = "<div>{{foo}}} and {{{bar}}} and {{{{hahahahahahahahaha}}}}</div>"
    var _res = string.match(/\{+(.*?)\}+/g).join("").split(/[\{\}]+/g)
    //Remove unwanted empty values
    var _finalOutput = _res.splice(1,_res.length-2)

    document.write(_finalOutput)
```